# While loop doesn't work when made into a function

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I can make this work:

```
function test1(){
    $count = 1;
    while($count < 8){
        echo "Hello world1 <br>";
        $count++;
    }
}
test1();
```

And I can make this work:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Hello world2<br>";
}
```

But I can't make this work:

```
function test2(){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Hello world3 <br>";
    }
}
test2();
```

The echo part is a placeholder for something else, but why doesn't the test2 function work?

Comment: When something works when not in a function, 99% of the time it's a scope issue.

Comment: What does a "scope issue" mean - just in a few more words so I know what to search the web for.

Comment: This => http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php will explain it.

Comment: Mysqli uses a connection ,the function has local scope so your connection has to be declared inside with the keyword global.

Comment: Try `function test2($db_connection,$result){` passing DB connection to the function. Most likely should fix it.

Comment: It was something along those lines that made it work, dannmate's solution below solved the problem. Thanks for input :)

Comment: You're welcome. My first comment was just `function test2($result){` but edited it, since I thought DB connection might've been playing a role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is the result variable is not defined before you call your function. You could try passing it in as a parameter in your test2 function as well. Like:

```
function test2($result){
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "Hello world3 <br>";
   }
}
test2($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

So this is probably a scope issue. Try echoing `$row` before the while loop as a single query. I can image you still wont see anything. My guess is that the `test2` function does not include the correct db information that you had when no function was involved.

Where is `$result` coming from?

The function has nothing showing what `$result` would equal

***Definition of scope from wiki:***

In computer programming, the scope of a name binding – an association of a name to an entity, such as a variable – is the part of a computer program where the binding is valid: where the name can be used to refer to the entity.

So in other words when you have a function

```
 $test = 10;
 foo();
 echo $test; // = 10 not 1

 foo(){
    $test = 1;
 }
```

This because the inside `$test` knows nothing about the outside $test.
Unless the variable is declared as a `global variable` (which is a variable that
can be understood by all functions). But if it was not declared as such this function will have no knowledge to the outside "world" in a sense.

You can also pass in a variable as a parameter to that the function shall contain these results in its `scope`

What you can do is:

```
 function func($result, $db){
    while($row = $db->mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "Hello world3 <br>";
    }
 }
```

Now the `scope` of the function contains `$result` and the `$db` so you can use them in the function